# Sales order vs sales order grid

Tags: database, magento2.3, orders

What is the difference between these two dB tables?

I can see for the data, the **sales_order_grid** appears to be a subset of **sales_order**. Is this true? What is the purpose of having duplicate tables (I assume it is to prevent lock ups).

If I have a custom module by which I want to add a field to an order, which table do I need to add the field to? And how do I ensure the data is consistent?

Answer (score 2):

`sales_order_grid` has less information about the order. It is basically used for **Admin order listing section**(Admin>Sales>Orders).

Where `sales_order` is main table and has much information. This data from table use on API, frontend order view, Order details admin etc.

So, if you want to add the new field to order, then you must need to add this new column or field to `sales_order` first, then if you want to show this field to grid then you can add this field to `sales_order_grid`.

`Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetup::addAttribute` is best method for add a column to order table and grid tablel

Data between grid  and mail table is update using [`Asynchronous order data processing`](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/configuration.html)

Comment: See details here about how `sales_order_grid` is refreshed from `sales_order`: https://medium.com/@sivaschenko/magento-2-adding-a-column-to-the-sales-order-grid-fca2f62c0b0c